# Responsive Background Header Image

Tags: css

I am trying to create a separate mobile site for ipad and smartphones. Everything has worked out fine so far but despite my best effort I can't get the header image right. I want it to be responsive to adjust to both phones and tablets (not desktop). Please help me out with this. This is the code in CSS.

```
    #headBanner {
background: url("header.jpg")
background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: 100%;
}  

#headBanner a, #headBanner a:visited {

color: #000000;

padding: 12px 0 0 8px;

font-size: 2.2em;

}
```

And this is the html code for the header section.

```
<div id="headBanner"><a href="example.com">Site Name</a></div>
```

Please help me out. I am completely frustrated. What code should I use and what size should I put for header image? I am using 320px by 80 px.

Comment: have you heard of - [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)?

Comment: Why doing all this by hand, you can use a framework like Bootstrap that handles all of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#headbanner{
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
              background-size: 100% auto !important;
}
```

This will fix the issue I think.

Comment: Won't do the job, as the OP mentioned:
"I am trying to create a separate mobile site for ipad and smartphones."

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and(max-width: 320px) {
    #headBanner {
        background: url("header.jpg")
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

You will have to use this function, but keep in mind that Retina (Apple products screen stuff) does have a specific resolution/pixel-ratio

You could take a look here : http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ 
they explain and have examples,
I've been stuck on exact the same thing, but i've got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of the best breakpoints (imo)

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px) { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

and some articles :

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries